# Use process.env variable in npm script

Tags: heroku, npm, environment-variables

I have a node.js app which i'm building/hosting on Heroku. I would like to use the environment variables set on Heroku when building my application. for example in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "build --option="MY_HEROKU_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"
}
```

is it possible to read those variables when the script is run?

Thanks in advance
/Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. What you can do instead is define a Node script to run, and have that script itself use environment variables.

For instance, what if your `postinstall` target was just `node postinstall.js`, and then inside of your `postinstall.js` script you read the `process.env.MY_HEROKU_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` value?